# mySQL- Trigger update a COUNT basic insert value

Tags: mysql

I want to create a trigger for my mySQL

1. Trigger after insert data to `my table A(id, i_Year=2017, i_Number=NULL)`
2. have a count-B from table A: count basic what I just `insert(New.i_Year)`
3. update count-B into i_Number in my table A

   ```
   DELIMITER $$
   CREATE TRIGGER  update_1
   AFTER INSERT ON TABLEA
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN

   UPDATE TABLEA
   SET TABLEA.i_Number = (SELECT COUNT(*)+1 FROM TABLEA WHERE TABLEA.i_Year = New.i_Year)
   FROM TABLEA 
   WHERE TABLEA.id = New.id;

   END$$
   DELIMITER ;
   ```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Reminder: Your problems should also be described in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the trigger to be `BEFORE INSERT` and set the count for te new row, e.g.:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  update_1
BEFORE INSERT ON TABLEA
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE row_count int;

SELECT COUNT(*)+1 INTO row_count FROM TABLEA WHERE TABLEA.i_Year = New.i_Year
SET NEW.i_Number = row_count;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```